# "JTS/JTA transaction has been aborted" in websphere 7 after jdk upgrade

Tags: websphere, java, websphere-7, ibm-jdk, java-transaction-service

I just had to upgrade my IBM JDK version from the one that came with the WebSphere 7 to fix an issue with Groovy.  Now however when my app starts up I get the following stack trace and the error kills my apps initialization good and proper.

2013-06-08 17:59:06,574~WebContainer : 10~ERROR~com.myapp.application.webui.spring.XmlWebApplicationContext~Failed to load context
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to load context; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JDBC transaction; nested exception is com.ibm.ejs.cm.exception.TransactionAbortedException: JTS/JTA transaction has been aborted
        at com.myapp.application.webui.spring.XmlWebApplicationContext.refresh(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at com.myapp.application.webui.spring.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:24)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1718)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:385)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:732)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:617)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)

If I switch back to old JDK I don't get this but I'm stuck with a known issue with Groovy.  Also there are currently a number of other websphere environments running the same war file without issue.

The version I upgraded to is 6.0.13.2 of the IBM JDK.  Running on Centos 6.4.  I also tried 6.0.10.

Googling the issue just shows other people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the IBM WebSphere JDK installs are not compatible with Websphere(???).  I found a fix in the websphere section that was a package (.pak file) of the JDK and installed that via the updater and now everything is working correctly.